# spaces in batch file argument passing?file not found

Tags: batch-file

i have a batch file that take input as

```
   @echo off
        cd /d "c:\program files\wireshark"
        set /p input= %1
        tshark  -T  fields -n -r  "%input%"  -E separator=,<some more code>
```

input using

```
       set /p input= %1
```

and set its path and using its value as

```
         "%input%"
```

so now we are goindf to run batch and excute by passing parameter by simple **double click** test and now i have to pass argument through c sharp

```
    string consolepath = @"""" +  Server.MapPath(FileUpload1.FileName) + "";
```

and get this path as

```
    p.StartInfo.Arguments = ""+consolepath+"";
```

it displays path but says error

> tshark to path "" file does not exist

**behaviour**

input value to variable input as argument in c sharp and then use it in code check question for detail?

how to set path now it shopw me full path but does noke it as input

Comment: `set /p input= %1` will prompt the user to set a value to `input` variable with the first argument passed.It will **not** assign the first argument to input.Are you sure this is the behavior you want?

Comment: actually on double click batch file when its window open i enter path `d:\sample.pcap` and it sets it path to `input` variable that is used as argument in below now i want to pass that argument using c sharp but it return the above error

Comment: HELLO you are right too

Comment: try with  `set "input=%~1"`